# Reading a 6.9GB file causes a segmentation fault

Tags: python

I'm trying to open the latest Japanese Wikipedia database for reading in Python 3.3.1 on Linux, but am getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error with this short program:

```
with open("jawiki-latest-pages-articles.xml") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

The file itself is quite large:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 fredrick users 7368183805 May 17 20:19 jawiki-latest-pages-articles.xml
```

So it seems like there is an upper limit to just how long a string I can store. What's the best way to tackle this situation?

My end goal is to count the most common characters in the file, sort of like a modern version of Jack Halpern's "Most Commonly Used Kanji in Newspapers". :)

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: Other people are addressing your iteration problem - obviously it's better to read line-by-line rather than try to hold 6+ GB in a single string.  For counting characters, look into the standard library's counters: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Any particular reason that isn't compressed with gzip, for example? XML compresses well, and for a ludicrously large file like that, you could save 3 to 4 GB just by compressing it. You could then open it using `gzip.open` in exactly the same way you are using `open` here, and gzip also decompresses fast, so the performance would be acceptable (possibly even faster than uncompressed).

Comment: Also note that even though your code does things in a foolishly naive way, your system should be brought to its knees without Python crashing first. That Python does crash probably indicates a bug in Python. Consider [reporting a bug](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: @kampu That's actually what I was curious about when writing the question, why it dumped the core. I expected it to use all my memory, so I was curious if there was some limit in Python.

Comment: @frb: Not an intentional one. It may be running afoul of a malloc() bug further down the line, or it may be making a stupid assumption. Using GDB to invoke python on your script, eg `gdb python` followed by `run myscript.py`, and finally `bt` when it crashes, may provide more information about the exact location of the crash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't read the whole article at once.  Even if your Python distribution is compiled as a 64-bit program (it's simply impossible to allocate more than 4 GB of virtual memory in a 32-bit program), and even if you have enough RAM to store it all, it's still a bad idea to read it all into memory at once.

One simple option is to read it a line at a time and process each line:

```
with open("jawiki-latest-pages-articles.xml") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Process one line
```

Alternatively, you can process it in fixed-size chunks:

```
while True:
    data = f.read(65536)  # Or any other reasonable-sized chunk
    if not data:
        break
    # Process one chunk of data.  Make sure to handle data which overlaps
    # between chunks properly, and make sure to handle EOF properly
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize `for` worked that way on file objects. That is very useful information.

Comment: Also note that if you wanted to process it as XML, you could use a stream-based XML parser, like the one provided in the [`xml.sax` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax). But for just counting characters in the file (including the XML tags), you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the program I eventually used, if anyone was curious.

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

progress = 0
with open("jawiki-latest-pages-articles.xml") as f:
    for line in f:
        progress += 1
        counter.update(line)
        if not progress%10000: print("Processing line {0}..., number {1}".format(line[:10], progress))

output = open("output.txt", "w+")

for k, v in counter.items():
    print("{0}\t{1}".format(k, v), file=output)

output.close()
```

Comment: You could use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index.